# Having problems with Nginx Proxy when running

Tags: docker, nginx, docker-compose, nginx-reverse-proxy

I have a problem with the Nginx Proxy, it doesn't appear in the CORS console, it can't be opened, even though it's already open in the Nginx settings.

```
map $http_upgrade $connection_upgrade {

  default upgrade;
  ''      close;
}

server {
    listen       80;
    server_name  localhost;
    proxy_http_version 1.1;

    location / {
        proxy_pass            http://0.0.0.0:4000;
        proxy_http_version    1.1;
        proxy_set_header      Host "$host";
        proxy_set_header      X-Real-IP "$remote_addr";
        proxy_set_header      X-Forwarded-For "$proxy_add_x_forwarded_for";
        proxy_set_header      X-Forwarded-Proto "$scheme";
        proxy_set_header      Upgrade "$http_upgrade";
        proxy_set_header      Connection $connection_upgrade;
        proxy_cache_bypass    $http_upgrade;
    }
    location = / {
        proxy_pass            http://0.0.0.0:3000;
        proxy_http_version    1.1;
        proxy_set_header      Host "$host";
        proxy_set_header      X-Real-IP "$remote_addr";
        proxy_set_header      X-Forwarded-For "$proxy_add_x_forwarded_for";
        proxy_set_header      X-Forwarded-Proto "$scheme";
        proxy_set_header      Upgrade "$http_upgrade";
        proxy_set_header      Connection $connection_upgrade;
        proxy_cache_bypass    $http_upgrade;
    }
    location ~ ^/(_next|node-api|apps|account|accounts|static|auth/profile|auth/unverified-email|txs|tx|blocks|block|login|address|stats|search-results|token|tokens|visualize|api-docs|csv-export|verified-contracts|graphiql|withdrawals) {
        proxy_pass            http://0.0.0.0:3000;
        proxy_http_version    1.1;
        proxy_set_header      Host "$host";
        proxy_set_header      X-Real-IP "$remote_addr";
        proxy_set_header      X-Forwarded-For "$proxy_add_x_forwarded_for";
        proxy_set_header      X-Forwarded-Proto "$scheme";
        proxy_set_header      Upgrade "$http_upgrade";
        proxy_set_header      Connection $connection_upgrade;
        proxy_cache_bypass    $http_upgrade;
    }
}
server {
    listen       8080;
    server_name  localhost;
    proxy_http_version 1.1;
    proxy_hide_header Access-Control-Allow-Origin;
    proxy_hide_header Access-Control-Allow-Methods;
    add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' '*' always;
    add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials' 'true' always;
    add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Methods' 'PUT, GET, POST, OPTIONS, DELETE, PATCH' always;

    location / {
        proxy_pass            http://0.0.0.0:8050/;
        proxy_http_version    1.1;
        proxy_set_header      Host "$host";
        proxy_set_header      X-Real-IP "$remote_addr";
        proxy_set_header      X-Forwarded-For "$proxy_add_x_forwarded_for";
        proxy_set_header      X-Forwarded-Proto "$scheme";
        proxy_set_header      Upgrade "$http_upgrade";
        proxy_set_header      Connection $connection_upgrade;
        proxy_cache_bypass    $http_upgrade;
    }
}
server {
    listen       8081;
    server_name  localhost;
    proxy_http_version 1.1;
    proxy_hide_header Access-Control-Allow-Origin;
    proxy_hide_header Access-Control-Allow-Methods;
    add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' '*' always;
    add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials' 'true' always;
    add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Methods' 'PUT, GET, POST, OPTIONS, DELETE, PATCH' always;
    add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Headers' 'DNT,Keep-Alive,User-Agent,X-Requested-With,If-Modified-Since,Cache-Control,Content-Type,Range,Authorization,x-csrf-token' always;

    location / {
        proxy_pass            http://0.0.0.0:8050/;
        proxy_http_version    1.1;
        proxy_buffering       off;
        proxy_set_header      Host "$host";
        proxy_set_header      X-Real-IP "$remote_addr";
        proxy_connect_timeout 30m;
        proxy_read_timeout    30m;
        proxy_send_timeout    30m;
        proxy_set_header      X-Forwarded-For "$proxy_add_x_forwarded_for";
        proxy_set_header      X-Forwarded-Proto "$scheme";
        proxy_set_header      Upgrade "$http_upgrade";
        proxy_set_header      Connection $connection_upgrade;
        proxy_cache_bypass    $http_upgrade;
        if ($request_method = 'OPTIONS') {
            add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' '*' always;
            add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials' 'true' always;
            add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Methods' 'PUT, GET, POST, OPTIONS, DELETE, PATCH' always;
            add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Headers' 'DNT,Keep-Alive,User-Agent,X-Requested-With,If-Modified-Since,Cache-Control,Content-Type,Range,Authorization,x-csrf-token' always;
            add_header 'Access-Control-Max-Age' 1728000;
            add_header 'Content-Type' 'text/plain charset=UTF-8';
            add_header 'Content-Length' 0;
            return 204;
        }
    }
}
```

Show Logs Console

[problem picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ufyi7.png)

I'm Using Docker Compose NGINX.

I hope that someone can help with this problem. I've changed as much as possible but no result